# .htaccess redirect rule for Parent Directory in href

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am developing a PHP MVC framework. I have a root directory in which all the Project directories are listed. There is a res folder in root where I put all my common stylesheets and scripts files, which will be used in other projects regularly. Like following:

```
root
   |__res
   |    |__scripts
   |    |__styles
   |
   |__project1
   |         |__.htacess
   |__project2
   |         |__.htacess
```

I am referencing the scripts from my projects like following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../res/styles/my.css"/>
<script src="/../res/scripts/my.js"></script>
```

Each Project has a .htaccess coofiguration. My htaccess configuration is:

```
Options -Indexes

#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I run my project on localhost, it runs perfectly, but when I run it at my online server,
I got 404 error

```
http://someurl.server.com/res/styles/my.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 101ms]


http://someurl.server.com/res/scripts/my.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 101ms]
```

I noticed that even the double dots, **../**, which are used to refer to parent directory from href are also removed, which doesn't happen on localhost or local server.

Earlier I was getting following error while running project on live server:

```
The stylesheet http://someurl.server.com/res/styles/w3.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”
```

I remove this error by including following line in htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
```

I am very new to htaccess, and lost. Please help.

Comment: Please do not spam tags that have no relevance to your question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, like what tags which are not relevant to my question?

Comment: You had CSS, PHP and mime-type, none of which are relevant to a question about mod-rewrite. Please do not edit again to include those.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, You are write. Sorry about that.

Comment: What is `someurl.server.com` pointing to as its DOCUMENT_ROOT? Sounds like that was pointed to `projectX` directly. You can not go above the document root with HTTP. In your local setup, you are probably accessing those projects via `localhost/project1/` and `localhost/project2/`, or something like that? That would be a completely different setup then.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes. I am accessing the projects like localhost/projectName/. And it's working. someurl.server.com is DOCUMENT_ROOT. What's the solution